# Im trying to implement a delete button using django and vue js

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-urls

Im trying to implement a delete button using django and vue js but im running into an error 500 and i cant seem to understand why ? i know it means my call isn't working

[image: when clicking on the yes, delete button im supposed to]

go from here

```
<button class="button is-success" @click="deleteTest()"> Yes, Delete</button>
```

to here

```
 deleteTest() {
                    axios.post('/app/api/testzone_delete/' + this.TestCategory_id + '/')
                        .then((response) => {
                            console.log(response)

                            this.showDialog = false
                        })
                        .catch((function (error) {
                            console.log(error )
                        }))
                }
            }
    })
    </script>
```

then like its django it goes through url.py

```
path('api/testzone_delete/<int:individualtestzone_id>/', api_delete_test, name='api_delete_test'),
```

and finally in the api.py

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt

from .models import TestCategory
from django.contrib import messages


@csrf_exempt
def api_delete_test(request, individualtestzones_id):
    individualtestzone = request.user.TestCategories.all().get(pk=individualtestzones_id)

    individualtestzone.delete()

    return JsonResponse({'success': True})
```

im pretty new to django and can't seem to see why it does not work

Answer (score -1, accepted):

so the answer was pretty stupid in my api function instead of individualtestzones_id i jad to put individualtestzone_id